# What is the system app "Bluetooth share" for?

Tags: applications, system-apps

I have a system app on my Android 7.0 android device. The app is called "Bluetooth share".

What exactly is this app used for?

Answer (score 0):

Bluetooth Share does what its name says.
It sends files wirelessly using Bluetooth

Try it out by going to a picture (or file), select Share, Bluetooth, and your recipient bluetooth device